# Passing variable arguments to custom EL function possible?

Tags: facelets, el, jsf-1.2, variadic-functions

I wanted support for a custom function call with parameters in JSF-1.2 and came across this doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio.

But is it possible to use variable arguments to that function?

I tried by using arrays in `Tag Library` but looks like JSF doesnt recognize the function in that case.

Answer (score 4):

No, EL method expressions do not support varargs. Not in the current [EL 2.2 version](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html), also not in the future [EL 3.0 version](http://java.net/projects/el-spec).

You need to look for an alternative approach. As the concrete functional requirement is unclear, I can't recommend any one.

---

**Update**: the functional requirement is thus:

> *I have to use parameterized messages from the Message Bundle in the JavaScript involved in my page. Something like an Error or Alert message on trying to delete a file that has the filename parameterized in the message bundle.*

Well, there are no smart workarounds to go around that. You have 2 options:

1. Create a bunch of EL functions taking a different amount of arguments.

   ```
   #{my:format1(...)}
   #{my:format2(...)}
   #{my:format3(...)}
   ...
   ```
2. Extend `<h:outputFormat>` to store the result in a request scoped variable instead of printing it.

   ```
   <my:outputFormat ... var="foo">
       <f:param ... />
       <f:param ... />
       <f:param ... />
       ...
   </my:outputFormat>

   ...
   #{foo}
   ```

The [OmniFaces JSF utility library](http://omnifaces.org) for JSF2 has both solutions in flavor of [`<o:outputFormat>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat) and several [`of:formatX()` functions](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings). It's not useable on JSF 1.x, but it's open source and should provide some insight.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response,@Balusc!! Actually, I have to use parameterized messages from the Message Bundle in the JavaScript involved in my page.

Something like an Error or Alert message on trying to delete a file that has the filename parameterized in the message bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a list or array to the custom function.

Warning: this code is untested and might make you feel dirty - it is a complete hack.

We need two artefacts registered as managed beans.

1) A subverted `Map` type:

```
/** Important: must be none-scoped */
public class ArrayBuilder extends AbstractMap<Object, Object> {

  private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

  @Override public Object get(Object entry) {
    if(entry instanceof MakeArray) {
      return list.toArray();
    } else {
      list.add(entry);
      return this;
    }
  }

  @Override public Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }
}
```

A poison pill to trigger array creation:

```
/** should be application scoped bean */
public final class MakeArray {
}
```

The EL expression:

```
#{fn:foo(arrayBuilder['one']['two']['three'][makeArray])}
```

The intent of the code is to pass an `Object` array containing three strings to the function `foo`.

*I have no idea if this actually works.*